# Questsion about using HAVING in ACCESS SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I wanted to get clarity on how the HAVING component in an SQL statement works, particularly with a SQL statement that has multiple joins.  Consider the following SQL select statement:

```
SELECT 
   p.id,
   p.first_name as [First Name], 
   p.last_name as [Last Name]
FROM
   ( [tbl_person] as p  
 INNER JOIN [tbl_person_languages] as pl 
    ON [p].[id] = [pl].[person_id])
 INNER JOIN [tbl_person_crossCuttingSkills] As ccp 
    ON [p].[id] = [ccp].[person_id]
WHERE  
   cint(pl.language_id) in (12,14) AND 
    cint(ccp.skill_id) in (55) 
GROUP BY  
   p.id,
   p.first_name, 
   p.last_name
HAVING 
    count(pl.language_id) =2 AND 
    count(ccp.skill_id) = 1
```

I want to pull out records, from tbl_person, where a record has all of the WHERE requirements.  For example:  I want to select all users where they speak a languages Italian (with ID 12) and Spanish (ID 15) AND have a skill of cooking (55).  They need to have all requirements, not just one or more.  I was under the assumption this is where you would use GROUP BY and HAVING.  With the HAVING:

```
  count(pl.language_id) =2
```

I use count = 2 because there are two options in the language WHERE clause (12 and 14)

And I use

```
 count(ccp.skill_id) = 1
```

Because there is one value in the WHERE clause (55).

Is this the correct way to be doing this?  For some reason, this returns no records (I have one record in my DB of a person who fits these requirements exactly).  But, if I change my HAVING to:

```
count(pl.language_id) =2 AND 
count(ccp.skill_id) = 2
```

It works fine.  Why is this?  Are my assumptions of how this works incorrect or is there something else going on?

Comment: It means that no one person with the same, id, firstname, and lastname has 2 languages, and 1 skill. There may be instances of 2 languages and 2 skills like you mentioned. Given your where clause, how many of languages/skills do you see? Is it possible to provide a small amount of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember what `count()` does . . . it counts non-NULL values.  So, you are counting two non-NULL values then the counts are the same.

In most dialects of SQL, you can fix this by doing:

```
HAVING count(distinct pl.language_id) = 2 AND count(distinct ccp.skill_id) = 1
```

But that doesn't work in MS Access, because MS Access does not support `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.

So, you can be more verbose.  In your case:

```
HAVING SUM(iif(cint(pl.language_id) = 12, 1, 0)) > 0 AND
       SUM(iif(cint(pl.language_id) = 14, 1, 0)) > 0 AND
       SUM(iif(cint(ccp.skill_id) = 55, 1, 0)) > 0
```

I'm sorry this `HAVING` clause is not simpler.  You *could* switch to another database (such as SQL Server Express) that more closely aligns with ANSI functionality.

Comment: There is no chance that the same person will have the same language or skill more than once.  I still cant see why this does not work, then.  I have a person with these two lanaguate ID's and skill ID but it still returns an empty data set

Comment: That is because `count(ccp.skill_id)` returns 2, if two rows match all the other conditions.

Comment: is there a way to account for this in my SQL?  Or is it best to do this through code?  Unfortunate, Access is our only option.

Comment: Holly crap, that did it!  Thanks!  I didn't think I would need that part, as I know in my DB, a person cant have the same FK more than once, but this seems to work!